# open a modal form from my usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have  a usercontrol that opens a form. i want this form to open as modal having its parent the same parent of the usercontrol. is that possible? (all i need is that the form is open modal).

when i tried (form.parent = this.parent) i got an error saying the form is a toplevel form.
then i tried (form.toplevel=false; form.parent=this.parent) and here i got a cross-thread operation error.

thanks for helping.

---

Hans, here are parts of my code, thanks.

```
private void Container_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs args)   
{

         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                delegate(object state)
                {

                    object[] parameters = (object[])state;
                    object s = parameters[0];
                    DragEventArgs e = parameters[1] as DragEventArgs;
                    this.OnContainerDragandDrop(s, e);

                },
                new object[] { sender, args });
}

private void OnContainerDragandDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
    //here I am calling a method
    MyMethod(e)
    }

private void MyMethod(DragEventArgs e)
{
mywcfClient.MyrequestWasSuccessfull += new MyRequestInfoEventHandler(mywcfClient_MyrequestWasSuccessfull);
}

void  mywcfClient_MyrequestWasSuccessfull (object sender, MyRequestInfoEventargs args)
{

//this is where I wanna show my form
From frm = new Form();
Frm.showdialog() //here the form is showing but non modal, i want to show it as modal}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hum to have a user control open a form, consider raising an event so that the control's parent form stays in control and displays the dialog.

But okay if the dialog is a complete implementation detail of the control.  Don't set the Parent, you need to use the ShowDialog(owner) overload if you want to pick a specific owner.  It isn't typically necessary, the ShowDialog() method goes hunting for a suitable owner if you don't specify one.  You can find the parent form of the control back with code like this:

```
    private Form GetParentForm() {
        var parent = this.Parent;
        while (!(parent is Form)) parent = parent.Parent;
        return parent as Form;
    }
```

But you've got another problem, also the reason why you asked this question in the first place.  Your dialog right now doesn't have an owner and it is likely to disappear behind another window.  That's because your code runs on another thread.  A thread that created no windows, and thus can't supply an owner window, and the reason for the cross-thread exception message.

You need to use Control.Invoke to run the dialog code on the UI thread.  There's a good example of it in the MSDN Library topic for it.

Comment: thanks Hans, you are right, the code trying to open the form is running in another thread,  can you give me a specific example of how can i invoke on how to run the showdialog on the UI thread?

Comment: I can't give a specific example on a very nonspecific question without any snippets that show how the dialog is intended to be used.  That I guessed that threading was the problem was a lucky guess.  Did you look at the MSDN article for Control.Invoke()?

Comment: Hans, i tried to invoke the control (meaning that calling the showdialog from with a methodinvoker delegate) but the problem is that i get an error saying (you cannot invoke a form before its window handle is created, and the window handle, to my knowledge, is created after the window is shown)

Comment: I refreshed the page for a while.  Edit your question.  Your snippet shows no evidence of any Control.Invoke call, I cannot guess why it doesn't work when I can't see the code that doesn't work.  I think I'll throw the towel on this one, you know the source of the problem, good luck with it.